# Can I use signalr with Asp .Net (not ASP. Net core)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I am confused about SignalR if it can work on asp.net (not asp. Net core). I am building a project in ASP.NET but cannot find any resource or example that mention that SignalR can works on Asp. Net in which pages work heavily on Page Postback.

I feel the question little bit stupid.. But i am really confused...

Please give me a hand, and if Yes, it is working, please lead me to some tutorials..

I searched youtube and google to confirm or find an example but there was no luck...

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about an application targeting .Net Framework 4.8 or lower. Yes, SignalR still works there. Search for the phrase "SignalR 2".

Comment: SignalR predates core...

Answer (score 3):

For ASP.NET `.NET Framework` (4.8 and back) you will want to look for the following nuget packages:

> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core
> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client

**Be careful not to mistake for** Microsoft.*AspNetCore*.SignarlR.Core

I have a working RESTful web API that still targets .NET 4.7.2 and incorporates a Chat hub which I connect to through an Angular user interface which uses NPM package `signalr` version 2.4.3.

Here is a Microsoft article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/